# How to use two NSPredicates for fetch request - Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I was trying to use two `NSPredicate`s for a single fetch request by doing,

```
let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "object1 == nil", "object1")
let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "object2 == nil", "object2")
let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicateType.OrPredicateType, subpredicates: [predicate1, predicate2])

request.predicate = predicate
```

the objects are a subclass of `NSManagedObject` and I am trying to fetch all items that have not got a relation with either object.

However it does not seem to be working, can someone have any suggestions on where I may be going wrong ?

Comment: You're not binding anything in your predicates, so they shouldn't be `NSPredicate(format: "object1 == nil", "object1")` but instead `NSPredicate(format: "object1 == nil")`

Comment: @sschale that didn't seem to work, for a single predicate I use            `request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "object1 == nil", "object1")` and that works

Comment: You can just use OR in a predicate, so you should be able to use `NSPredicate(format: "(object1 == nil) OR (object2 == nil)")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "object1 == nil && object2 == nil", "object1","object2")
```